# Dishwasher install, no power

Tags: electrical, installation, dishwasher

I just installed a GE dishwasher. When I turned the breaker on, it had no power. The wall and dishwasher both have 3 wires, black (hot), white (neutral), and green (ground). I have 120VAC from ground to hot, but not ground to neutral. Should I not have 120V between any 2 wires?

Comment: I aslo have 120V between hot and neutral

Comment: no ... you should not have 120 V between ground and neutral ..... is that the only question that you have?

Comment: Then why would I not be getting any lights or anything on the control panel? It's acting like it has no power.

Comment: I press all the buttons and nothing happens.

Comment: hard wired of plugged into an outlet?  did you use a switched outlet?

Comment: Hard wired, no switch.

Comment: Ground to neutral should be near 0V in a healthy electrical system.  Can you turn the breaker for that circuit off and test for continuity between ground and neutral, by the way?

Comment: Yes, I have continuity between ground and neutral.

Comment: Are you certain that the power cable connected to the plug is actually connected to the right lugs inside the dishwasher?  Sometimes they ship dishwashers with a power cord that is in the right physical location and terminated in the junction box, but not actually attached to the internal screws.

Comment: I checked power going to the pins on the plug that connects to the circuit board. There was power going to the board.